# Cloning object in fabricjs from one canvas to another messes up the controls

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have two canvases where I am making an object on one canvas and cloning it to another for further use. I am achieving this by using

> var cloned_rect = fabric.util.object.clone(clone_rect);

After cloning the object onto the target canvas, the object has it's controls messed up. Also I have `transparentCorners: false` on the source canvas, that is disabled after cloning.

[image: messed up controls]

I have recreated the problem in this [jsFidde](https://jsfiddle.net/AmPhIbIaN26/z67kr0p8/31/).

```js
var canvasEl1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx1 = canvasEl1.getContext('2d');
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');

var canvasEl2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctxPrint = canvasEl2.getContext('2d');
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');

function selectAllObjects(desiredCanvas) {
  desiredCanvas.discardActiveObject();
  var sel = new fabric.ActiveSelection(desiredCanvas.getObjects(), {
    canvas: desiredCanvas,
  });
  desiredCanvas.setActiveObject(sel);
  desiredCanvas.requestRenderAll();
}

function makeRect() {
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    fill: 'white',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    transparentCorners: false
  });

  canvas1.add(rect);
}

function cloneRect() {
  
  selectAllObjects(canvas1);
  
  var clone_rect = canvas1.getActiveObject();
  var cloned_rect = fabric.util.object.clone(clone_rect);
  
  canvas2.add(cloned_rect);
  canvas2.renderAll();
  canvas1.renderAll();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@5.2.1/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <body>
    <div style="float:left">
      <canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="200" style="padding: 3px; border: solid;">
      </canvas>
      <br>
      <canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="200" style="padding: 3px; border: solid;">
      </canvas>
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="makeRect()">Make Rectangle</button>
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="cloneRect()">Clone Rectangle</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added the code to the question.